# create variable by matching variable value to object value?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm attempting to create a variable that contains the value of an object. 
the variable `eventDateValue` below is what i'm struggling with. I'm trying to match the value of `EventName` to the object `events2020` and if there's a match (must match the object name) pass the value of that match to the variable `eventDateValue`.

below is my code

```
function getPage(){
    let pageActual = window.location.href;
    console.log(pageActual);

    let pageName = /127(.*)/;
    let EventName = pageName.exec(pageActual);
    console.log(EventName[1]);

    const events2020 = {
        Event1 :'February 19, 2020',
        Event2 :'February 18, 2020',
        Event3 :'February 17, 2020',
        Event4 :'February 16, 2020',
        Event5 :'February 15, 2020',
        Event6 :'February 14, 2020'
    };

    let eventDateValue = Object.keys(events2020)

    [Object.values(events2020).indexOf(EventName)] 

    console.log(eventDateValue);
}
```

Comment: `Object.keys` gives you an array of keys, not a single value. Also, what is that `[.....]` line supposed to do?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is `let eventDateValue = events2020[EventName]`

Comment: Let me add some context, I'm writing a script that fires off an event based on the event date . It looks at the current date and compares it to the day the event starts. If it matches it triggers a CSS change. I have over 154 events in total so I'm trying to automate this. I wrote a function that essentially takes the current page address after the' .com '  and creates an event name. Example : event.com/eventname. It stores this in a variable. Im now attempting to match the event name to one of the events in my events object in order for the  browser to determine the current date for the event